# Convert column of type INT which stores date value in YYYYMMDD format to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, format

I have a column of type INT which stores date value in YYYYMMDD format. I want to display this as DD/MM/YYYY

I have tried below using the FORMAT function but do not get the result correct

I want to display this as 31/12/2050

[image: FORMAT Function]

I have tried as shown in the picture and I am expecting date value to be displayed as

31/12/2050

[image]

Comment: Please type your code into your question rather than posting an image. Same goes for the expected results. A lot of us do this in our breaks at work and since the file sharing Cyber Incident sites like Imgur are blocked

Comment: Format won't convert a number to a date, you are going to have to extract the the different values and build a date from them. All pretty straightforward stuff.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as integers? Why do you want to display them in a regional and ambiguous format? Why don’t you let the client format them instead of forcing SQL Server to do it?

Comment: Consider using column type `date` instead of `int` to store dates. This will improve data integrity (only valid dates can be stored) and avoid the need to convert the value to a date before formatting for display purposes, which should be done by the client rather than in T-SQL.

Comment: Just use `DATEFROMPARTS` and some arithmetic. `DATEFROMPARTS(value / 10000, value / 100 % 100, value % 100)`. Then format it in your presentation layer or use `CONVERT` with a style parameter

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(
        '/',
        SUBSTRING(CAST(date_column AS VARCHAR(8)), 7, 2),
        SUBSTRING(CAST(date_column AS VARCHAR(8)), 5, 2),
        SUBSTRING(CAST(date_column AS VARCHAR(8)), 1, 4)
    ) AS formatted_date
FROM your_table;
```

- `SUBSTRING(date_column, start_position, length)` extracts a substring from the `date_column` starting at `start_position` and with a length of `length`.
- `CONCAT()` combines these substrings with the slashes to form the desired format.

This query will output the dates in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

In this query, `CONCAT_WS` takes care of adding the separator '/' between the different date components, making the query more concise and readable.

I sent a sample query over my own ready template. You can customize this template for your project.

Comment: Last edit :D. I loved your thinks btw.

Comment: Instead of all those casts why not work with the integer? e.g.
`declare @d int = date_column % 100; -- day
declare @m int = ((date_column- @d) / 100) % 100 -- Month
declare @y int = date_column / 10000 -- Year
select FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(@y, @m, @d),'MM/dd/yyyy')`

Comment: I think, with integer describe would be can occur an error @CHill60

Comment: Well using an integer to store a date  in the first place could definitely lead to an error :laugh: - but what error are you referring to?